# Ensuring exploratory study's validity with pseudo-simple random sampling

Tags: sampling, cross-validation, missing-data

The *context* of my questions is as follows. I'm performing a *cross-sectional secondary research study*, involving *open source software (OSS)* projects. I collect data (information about the projects) from several sources, mostly OSS *repositories*. While I don't have exact statistics on that, I believe that projects, listed in those repositories represent a lion's share of the total OSS projects in existence (my estimate is around 90-95 percent, as some OSS projects are still listed on organizational websites). Technically, I'm able to collect most of the projects' data from repositories and I'm doing it for convenience and feasibility reasons. For clarity, below I will use `OSS_World` and `OSS_Repos` to refer to the corresponding data sets.

One of the problems with `OSS_Repos` data set is that it has a significant ratio of *missing data* in some categories, where categories essentially feed data for my study's *latent variable indicators*. This certainly seems like a *threat to validity* of the proposed study. However, I have no reason to believe that the data is missing due to some *systemic factors*, since there are no existing theories or studies that prove otherwise, and assume that.

My **questions** are the following:

**A)** Considering that my study is *exploratory* in nature, can I:

- make the above-mentioned *assumption* and consider the *validity* of the study acceptable (by exploratory research standards);
- use *simple random sampling* from the subset of `OSS_Repos` data, which excludes all observations with missing data (later referred to as `OSS_Repos_Nonmissing`);
- still consider this a simple random sampling, rather than stratified, and, thus, the sample `OSS_Repos_Nonmissing` *representative* of the population?

**B)** It is my understanding that I can **statistically support** my assumption (hypothesis) about non-systemic nature of data missingness by using `MCAR` tests, such as one developed by Little (1988) and its more modern cousin by Jamshidian, Jalal and Jansen (2014). Hopefully, these tests will support my `MCAR` hypothesis. However, if not, should I test sample on missing data being `MAR`?

**References**

Jamshidian, M., Jalal, S., & Jansen, C. (2014). MissMech: An R package for testing homoscedasticity, multivariate normality and missing completely at random (MCAR). *Journal of Statistical Software, 56*(6), 1-30. Retrieved from http://www.statsoft.org/v56/i06

Little, R. J. A. (1988). A test of missing completely at random for multivariate data with missing values. *Journal of the American Statistical Association, 83*, 1198-1202.